# Version Control Worflow Problems with AWS Lambda functions

Tags: reactjs, git, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I have created a React app that uses AWS lambda functions for the backend and is hosted on amplify. Git is used for version control. As the codebase scales, and multiple people are working on it, we have had lots of issues with how to manage the AWS lambda version control. Here is our current proccess:

The Amplify deployment pulls from Git and deploys the frontend of the site which acceses Lambda resources deployed on the console. To edit the app locally you can run it on your localhost and change the React app. In order to test the lambdas however, you have to deploy them on the console in AWS. This is an issue because in order to deploy the lambdas in the console, you have to run an **amplify push** command to push your lambda to the console. The problem arises because since that pushes it to the global console that everyone shares, it will overwrite functions others are editing with your current local environment ultimately going outside the version control environment and causing confusion.

I know you can use SAM or amplify mock to test lambdas locally, but this still gives us the error of eventually you have to **amplify push** it to the console and any time you do that it will push all of your local function versions even the ones other have edited.

I think we need something like **amplify pull** like a **git pull** but it looks like a**mplify pull** doesn't pull source code only configuration information.

I had hoped that amplify pull and push worked like git where it would enforce version control but it does not.

Comment: Have you looked at branch deployments in Amplify? I'm not sure exactly how they work with the CLI, but I do know you can deploy an amplify app from a branch and access it via a unique URL for that branch.